# Using .htaccess to redirect if file isn't found with Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have an issue where we are merging a website with Wordpress. The website has a ton of news stories in a "/news" directory that we need to keep. When we add the CMS at say "/wordpress" we can set the base URL to the root of the directory so when we make a new post in the category "news", the link for it is "/news/this-is-the-post-title", except the REAL location is "/wordpress/news/this-is-the-post-title". So my issue is that we want to keep all news stories at the "/news" URL, and in my head we just need the .htaccess to say "if the requested URL doesn't exist in the /news directory, try /wordpress/news", and of course if Wordpress doesn't find anything, it can 404. Hope this makes sense, thank you!

Comment: If you set the base URL of WordPress to `/wordpress` all of your URLs will live under that, categories, posts, pages, etc. Unless you mean your RewriteBase?

Comment: Hm, I think I do need to clear one thing up. I would like to have it always appear as "/news" no matter if the file is actually in the /news directory, or if it is in the /wordpress/news category. I am just unfamiliar with how .htaccess goes about doing that.. so I never want to actually see /wordpress in the URL. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand how the original news stories are held. But, if they are grabbed with PHP then you should be able to redirect to `/wordpress/news/post-title` if it doesn't exist.

On the other hand, if the news stories are static files you can check for them with `.htaccess` and make sure the file exists on the server.

```
# Goes in the "news" directory
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /news

  # These make sure the file or directory doesn't exist
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

  # Redirect to /wordpress/news/whatever-entered-goes-here
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wordpress/news/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Reference: http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/mod_rewrite-cheat-sheet/

Comment: The news stories are actual files in the /news directory right now, so its as basic as it can be. I made a comment above that I may have worded one thing incorrectly, and that is I always want the URL to appear as "/news/post-title", and never want to see the "/wordpress" in the URL.. I am not sure if that is what RewriteRule is doing, I need to read into that. Thank you for what you have put so far!!!

Comment: At first glance, it is looking like the changing the [R] to [NC] solves my problem! The [R] was putting the /wordpress into the URL, and now it always is /news, and works just as I had wanted. Unless this is bad or incorrect, I will post it as the answer. Thanks again.

Comment: I've updated my script, although I'm not completely sure this will work. But, I changed it so that if you go to "/news/post-title" it will check for a file, and if the file doesn't exist it will silently redirect back to WordPress. And then WordPress will be able to check if the post exists. And if it doesn't, WordPress should make the 404 error.

Comment: That appears to work as well, and actually removing the bracket portion seems to behave the same. I wish I knew what best practice is.. [NC] or [L] or [NC,L] or nothing at all!? Still doing my research, thank you for the quick response and any further advice.

Answer (score 0):

If you only use WordPress and static pre-existing directories and files (and not another CMS, next to WordPress), you can probably just follow the directions on [giving WordPress its own directory](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory). All WordPress files go to `wordpress/`, only the `index.php` and `.htaccess` are copied back to the root directory. The standard `.htaccess` from WordPress already has the two `RewriteCond` rules that check for existing files, so if the request is for `news/happy-2010.html` and this file already exists, your server will just serve this and not start WordPress.